# how can i purchase in app billing version3 android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am new to the inappbilling integration for android.I am using the develop the following link

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample

and also TrivialDrive import my eclipse and generate to the apk and export apk in googleplaystoreconsole of drafts not in published and also created to the product item and put in product id to my activity and

add to the String base64EncodedPublicKey="RSA public key". finally run the code showing following screen

[image]

also ways showing this screen .i didn't understand what is going on rightnow.please help me anyone known and idea about this advance thaks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. I contacted as well and got this response from Google

Thank you for contacting Google Play Developer Support and reporting the behavior you're seeing with in-app billing.

We recently made some changes to our systems and we are now requiring an app to be published before testing. We are currently recommending to publish your APK to the Alpha channel in order to test licensing, in-app billing, and expansion files. There is no need to create a special testing group in the Alpha channel to test these features, however the app must be published and not in draft mode.

We apologize for the inconvenience and are working to update our documentation to reflect these changes.

After publishing my APK to Alpha (as I haven't launched yet) and waiting an hour or so, my IAP test purchases started working again.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#draft_apps this link used to run in static response is correct or not

Comment: how to add the prices and product id dynamically to my app

Comment: Google is not provideing to add price dynamically so, if you want to do this then you have to create multiple sku pakage(product id) for different prices so, you can use this according to your requirement.